# Adjusting time for date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have two `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects, say `t1` and `t2`. What's the best way to change the hour and minute of `t2` to match that of `t1`. For example, say `t1` is 4/2/2012 at 3:45pm and `t2` is 4/15/2012 at 6:00pm. I want to change `t2` to be 4/15/2012 at 3:45pm.

I'm happy with solutions that work with `Time` objects as well.

I have this so far:

`Time.zone.parse "#{t1.strftime "%Y-%m-%d"} #{t2.strftime "%H:%M:%S"}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd just use Time.mktime. The whole ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone is a bit tedious, though.
With ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, I'd suggest:

```
t1 = Time.mktime(2012,4,15,18)
t2 = Time.mktime(2012,4,15,15,45)
t3 = Time.mktime(t1.year, t1.month, t1.day, t2.hour, t2.min, 0, 0, Time.zone.utc_offset).in_time_zone(Time.zone)
```

In plain ruby, you'd just do the first part:

```
t1 = Time.mktime(2012,4,15,18)
t2 = Time.mktime(2012,4,15,15,45)
t3 = Time.mktime(t1.year, t1.month, t1.day, t2.hour, t2.min)
```

As for the performance difference, mktime (including the .in_time_zone stuff) is about 15x faster here (Time.zone.parse taking 0.49ms, Time.mktime taking 0.03ms).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
t2.change(hour: t1.hour, min: t1.min)
```

[Documentation.](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Time/Calculations.html#M000192)

Comment: Specifically, this seems to be one of the features in the Time class as extended by Rails.  The documentation link seems to be bad, but you can do to http://api.rubyonrails.org/ and search for Time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but a Time object can be added to or subtracted from directly (seconds are the default unit of time, but it doesn't matter in this case).  Assuming t2 is a Time object, this simple code will give you an updated t2 with the time that matches t1:

```
t2 = 2012-04-15 18:00:00 -0400 # This is how a Time object is displayed in irb
t2 = t2 - (t2 - t1) # I did this in irb with require 'active_support', but it should work in Rails 3.x.
```

I'm relatively new to Rails so forgive me if I'm oversimplifying, but I hope this solves your problem.